# Get a specific item from a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check if the first item from the string is wrapped in HYML tags. I can have the next situations:

1. `"nothtml <p>"` // expect false
2. `"<p> "` //expect true
3. `"  <p> "` //expect true
4. `"<span>text "` //expect true

    In all situations i need to get the expected value.

```js
const s = '<p>test <p>';

console.log(s.split('<'))
console.log(/<\/?[a-z][\s\S]*>/i.test(s[0]));
```

According to the above idea, i want to split() the string and to get the first element, but i can't manage all situations when the first item could be not only `<p>, but also <span>, <div>,` how you can notice the length of the html tag can be different. Basically i need to find a solution to split the elements that are wrapped in tags `<element>`. How to do that?

Comment: Where is the code running? Can't you just parse the string as HTML and check whether the first node is an element (vs a text node)?

Comment: what are you meaning by splitting the elements that are wrapped in tags <element>? could you provide some examples and what you expect as the output?

Comment: @FelixKling, how to do that?

Comment: @AhmedHany, i need to chack if the string is starting with a tag, for this i need to split the string and to get the first element, if the fisrt element is not a tag, it will return false

Comment: @FelixKling, can you help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expressions to test your string.

See below regex, it checks if it's starting with HTML tag element with ignoring any space before the tag

```
/^\s*(\<\w+\>[\s\S]*\<\/\w+\>)/.test("nothtml <p>") // return false
```

and if you want to get the element

```
/^\s*(\<\w+\>[\s\S]*\<\/\w+\>)/.exec("      <element>dsa</element>")[1]
```

feel free to update the regular expression based on your needs, there are plenty of examples over the internet of how to validate HTML string using regular expressions.

Comment: why in this case /^\s*(\<\w+\>[\s\S]*\<\/\w+\>)/.test("<p>"), also is false?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I suggested in the comments, namely to parse text as HTML and inspect the first node. This example assumes a browser environment but there are HTML parsers available for Node.js as well. It also assumes that the input can be parsed as HTML.

```js
function isWrapped(text) {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  container.innerHTML = text.trimStart();
  return container.childNodes[0]?.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE; 
}

console.log(isWrapped('foo <p>test</p>'));
console.log(isWrapped('<p>test</p>'));
console.log(isWrapped('<p'));
```

Comment: testing `console.log(isWrapped(' <p>test</p>'));`, return false, but it should be true.

Comment: @Asking: You can trim leading white space with `text.trimStart()` before parsing it.

Comment: also, when i try `console.log(isWrapped('<p'))`, i get an error.

Comment: Yes, there will be no children if the input cannot be parsed as HTML. As I mentioned in the answer, I assumed the input can be parsed as HTML. If that's not the case then add a check that `childNodes[0]` exists. If it does not exist then you know it's not wrapped...

Comment: could you show please the changed code with this fix in your answer? It will help me a lot